# When is $M \times N$ contained in$ M \otimes_{R} N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring with 1. $M$ is a right R-module and $N$ is a left R-module. A tensor product of M and N comes with a map from $M \times N \to M\otimes N$ which is actually a composition of maps obtained from $M \times N \to F_{\mathbb{Z}}(M \times N) \to M\otimes N$ where $F_{\mathbb{Z}}(M \times N)$ is free abelian group over $M\times N$. the first map is an injection while the second is a surjection. My question is

Is there a condition when we can state that this composition of maps is an injection?

Comment: If $r\in R$ and $(m,n)\in M\times N$, the image of $(mr,n)$ and $(m,rn)$ in $M\otimes_R N$ is the same, right? Injectivity would imply $mr=m$ and $n=rn$, i.e. $m(r-1)=0$ and $(r-1)n = 0$ for all $m\in M,n\in N$. Putting $1+1$ for $r$, we obtain $m=n=0$, i.e. $M$ and $N$ are required to be trivial modules. This is of course sufficient.

Comment: it is sufficient for either M or N to be trivial as Martin points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when $M=N=0$. Look at $0 \otimes n = 0 = m \otimes 0$.

Comment: Should be $M = N = 0$.